# Downgrade/rollback IndexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb

I'm facing a situation where I may need to rollback my web app to a previous version because of a bug in the new version that will take some time to be fixed.

I know IDB supports the upgradeneeded event but I don't really see a way to downgrade it to a previous version.

Initially I thought it would be enough to handle the downgrade migration logic in the same upgradeneeded handler, but I realized IDB will error out as soon it finds my code is trying to use a version lower than what the DB is currently using.

What's the proper way to handle this common scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You really have two choices:

- Detect the bad version, delete the database, and start from scratch. This would result in data loss if the data only exists on the client machine.
- Do an upgrade to yet another new higher version, and treat the rollback like another upgrade. If version N was your good version and N+1 is your buggy version, then upgrade to N+2:

  - An upgrade from N to N+2 is a no-op. Easy!
  - An upgrade from N+1 to N+2 is where you do your rollback logic.
  - An upgrade from <N to N+2 is the same code you had for your upgrade from <N to N.

Ideally you're keeping a README somewhere in your code that documents the history of versions and what changed with each. So you'd note that N+1 was buggy and N+2 was a rollback to N.